# Drop Event in jQuery EasyUI tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, tree

I am trying to drag an item into a jQuery EasyUI tree, and get the id of the node the item is dropped onto. I am able to get onDrop events to fire if I'm dragging a tree node onto another tree node, but nothing happens when I drag a non tree-node item from another div.

If I put the event into the div around the tree, that div's onDrop event fires, but I cannot get the id of the tree node dropped onto from there.

What do I need to do? Do I need to write my own EasyUI function to add the ondrop event to the tree divs? Or use jQuery to add the function to the divs? Something else?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Could you post the relevant code here or create a jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: It would be a ton of code, I would really have to simplify it. I am really looking for guidance on approach, more than exact code.

Comment: I tried to create a jsfiddle, but cannot get it to display anything. It works locally. http://jsfiddle.net/pRP63/

Comment: problem is that you have missed the libraries like jquery in your jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/pRP63/12/. its working but missinf still one lib, which has definition to `.tree()`, so could you add the lib into `external resources` section

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pRP63/59/ I have updated and I think all external resources are OK. However, I cannot get the json data to load, and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the jQuery EasyUI Tree demo, I see this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#tt').tree({
            dnd: true,
            url: 'tree_data.json'
        });
    });
</script>

<ul id="tt"></ul>
```

I tried this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#tt').tree({
            dnd: true,
            url: 'tree_data.json'
        });
    });
    $(function(){
        $('#tt2').tree({
            dnd: true,
            url: 'tree_data2.json'
        });
    });
</script>

<ul id="tt"></ul>
<ul id="tt2"></ul>
```

...and made a separate file 'tree_data2.json' with one item in it, and was then able to drag that item into the first tree. Although, oddly, the first tree jumped down a bit.

If one dug into the jQuery EasyUI Tree code one might find the necessary classes and event listeners that can be manually attached to elements, but the above seems simpler.

Comment: Yes, but this code shows dragging one tree node into another tree node, just from a different tree. I am trying to drag something not from a tree, into a tree. So far I still have no idea.

Comment: This is an interesting drag and drop demo: http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/dd/dnd2_demo.html